# How to find absolute path of error_log directive within nginx?

Tags: nginx, webserver, nginx-config, nginx-location

I am trying to debug an issue related to `nginx`.

The configuration file has below details:

```
error_log logs/error.log warn;
```

How can I determine the **absolute path** of the error logs?

Comment: Use `nginx -V` and you should see the value of the `--prefix` option (usually `/etc/nginx`). This should be the directory from which relative paths are taken. If the directory `logs` does not exist, the file creation will fail and an error should be written to the default error log (usually `/var/log/nginx/error.log`).